# Two Heaps with same key Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, key, heap

Hi if you have two heaps how do you determine if they have a key that is the same in O(nlogn) runtime, where n is the total size between the two min heaps.

I was thinking that it might be related to adding one of the heaps to the other but I am not positive.

Comment: It may be useful to mention which heap algorithm you are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool have_same_element(heap<int> h1, heap<int> h2) {
  while (!h1.empty() && !h2.empty()) {
    int t1 = h1.top(), t2 = h2.top();
    if (t1 == t2) return true;
    if (t1 < t2) h1.pop();
    else h2.pop();    
  }
  return false;
}
```

O(s1 ln(s1) + s2 ln(s2)) guarantee O(n ln(n)) where n = s1+s2;

Comment: +1. Exactly. What you have is essentially a merge of two sorted sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I think heap structure doesn't help to solve such task, so it doesn't matter if you have two heaps or two arrays of items. To find if two dataset have same value you can use different algorythms, i suggest  two for example:

1. You can put items of smaller set into any hash-based dictionary and then you can enumerate items of another set and check whether they are in first set. Probably it is fastest way, but takes some additional space for dictionary.
2. Let's suppose you have 2 classical heap structures kept in arrays (for heap it is possible). Then you can sort smallest array. After that just enumerate items of the second heap and use binary search to check if item is in first heap. 
   When you finish, you can rebuild your broken heap again (it is possible to do inline into same array wheere items are).
   So you get O(nlogn) where n is number of smaller heap and can do without additional memory usage.

Comment: (2) is `O(m log n)` (`m` being the larger size) because you look through each element in the larger list and do a `log n` lookup. Well, it's `O(n log n + m log n)` but `n log n < m log n`, so it simplifies to the above.

Comment: @Yes, you right. But anyway, it is same (even better) as nlogn, where n total size of both heaps.

Comment: Searching each element in the small heap from the large one seems better. It will cost O(Nln(M)) where N is the size of the small heap, M for the large one. It will be not worse than O(MlnN). Of course these are both better than O(nln(n)).

Comment: @notbad If we already have ordered set, yes, but we don't. We have to order one set, it is also nlogn. So from point of view of big O it doesn't matter what part we sort, but i think it is more efficient to sort small one.

Comment: @notbad It's more efficient to sort/search the smaller one - `O(n log n + m log n) = O(m log n)` vs `O(m log m + n log m) = O(m log m)`, and `O(m log m) > O(m log n)`.